# Cannot create Azure RBAC custom role using ARM Template

Tags: azure, rbac

I am unable to spin up Azure RBAC Roles using ARM templates. As per my template the parameter "actions" would be of type Array. It passes Validation but gives error during runtime. It runs fine however when I am using type String, passing one single action item as parameter.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "roleName": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "rbacGuid": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    "actions": {
        "type": "Array"
    }
},
"variables": {
},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions",
        "apiVersion": "2017-05-01",
        "name": "[parameters('rbacGuid')]",
        "properties": {
            "roleName": "[parameters('roleName')]",
            "IsCustom": true,
            "Description": "[parameters('description')]",
            "permissions": [
                {
                    "Actions": [
                        "[parameters('actions')]"

                    ],
                    "NotActions": []
                }
            ],
            "AssignableScopes": [
                "[subscription().id]"
            ]
        }
    }
],
"outputs": {        
}
```

}

Error I got:

```
az deployment sub create --location $location --template-file $templa ...

  + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Deployment fail...0cea05be18f1. {:String) [], RemoteException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

"error": {
  "code": "InvalidRequestContent",
  "message": "The content of your request was not valid, and the original object could not be deserialized. Exception message: 'Unexpected character encountered while
```

parsing value: [. Path 'properties.permissions[0].Actions', line 1, position 160.'"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this

```
                    "Actions": [
                        "[parameters('actions')]"

                    ],
```

And make it

```
            "Actions": "[parameters('actions')]",
```

See full example:

- [MSDN](http://Add%20Azure%20role%20assignments%20using%20Azure%20Resource%20Manager%20templates)
- [Github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/subscription-deployments/create-role-def/azuredeploy.json)